# Xcode Storyboard "Embed In" Scroll View blanks view controller OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, nsview, nsscrollview

I have created a View Controller with some content defined in it. When I embed that content in a ScrollView (using the "Embed In" from the "Editor" menu) then the content disappears when I run the application. Curiously if I only embed just one label in a scrollview then that single label still appears.

[image]
[image]

What is going on here. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Xcode in that it doesn't restore the constraints. I just tried and if you cut and then paste the views into the scroll view it will restore some, but not all the constraints. However, outlets will become detached, so it is not really a win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that when you first use the Embed In command it will correctly embed the objects into the form, but if there are no constraints then the objects are probably drawn offscreen. Setting constraints for the embedded objects caused them to be drawn correctly.

[image]

Simply select 'Reset to Suggest Contraints for all views in View Controller and it will start to work.

[image]

Hope this helps someone.